# OpenShift, Python Application run script every 10 min

Tags: python, openshift

How to create shedule on OpenShift hosting to run python script that parses RSS feeds and will send filtered information to my email? It feature is available? Please help, who works with free version of this hosting. I have script that works fine. But i dont know how to run it every 10 min to catch freelance jobs. Or anyone does know free hosting with python that can create shedule for scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the add-on cartridge that is called cron.  However, by default the cron cartridge only supports jobs that run every minute or every hour.  You would have to write a job that runs minutely to determine if its a 10 minute interval and then execute your script.

Make sense?

rhc cartridge add cron -a yourAppName

Then you will have a cron directory in application directory under .openshift for placing the cron job.

Answer (score 1):

You could so something like this here but setup for 10 minutes instead of 5: https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-cacti-quickstart/blob/master/.openshift/cron/minutely/cactipoll